# Будет ли работать Я.Метрика если ее скрипт кешируется и сжимается на сервере?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

При проверке скорости сайта на https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ сделал все что мог, но до зеленой зоны оставалось только указать контроль кеширования и сжатие для внешнего скрипта Яндекс.Метрики т.е. для

```
s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js";
```

Скопировал код данного файла и сохранил себе в папке сайта где остальные JS-файлы, а в инлайновом скрипте Метрики соответственно указал

```
s.src = "/path/to/js/yandex_metrika_tag.js";
```

В файле .htaccess указано кеширование

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
    Header set Pragma "max-age=86400"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

и сжатие

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

Вопрос: будет ли Яндекс.Метрика при этом нормально работать как и раньше?

Comment: Очень вряд ли, яндекс обновит этот скрипт без вашего ведома и всё сломается (но это не точно)

Comment: Ответа тут нет, но в тему: https://yandex.ru/blog/metrika-club/google-s-pagespeed-insights-snimaet-bally-za-kod-sch-tchika-yandeks-metriki

Comment: Работать будет. Я написал плагин на WP, который работает на  нескольких сайтах. Плагин скачивает скрипт метрики на свой сервер, и запускает её оттуда. Обновление скрипта метрики - по cron, 2 раза в сутки. Проблем нет.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а почему его нужно обновлять?

Comment: Он периодически обновляется Яндексом. На что это влияет, неизвестно. Лучше обновлять. Я также в свое плагине сохраняю скрипт Google Maps, так когда он не обновлялся из-за ошибок, то карты просто падали.

Comment: Вопрос решается следующим образом:
[https://www.lexium.ru/2020/01/yandex-metrika-storonnijj-kod-zablokiroval-osnovnojj-potok/](https://www.lexium.ru/2020/01/yandex-metrika-storonnijj-kod-zablokiroval-osnovnojj-potok/)